# External javascript while in the same directory as the html file, does not work

Tags: javascript, html

Both the html file and the js file are in the same directory, yet somehow im missing something...

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tiles</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="c1" width="200" height="100">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script src="tiles.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My JS file:

```js
function tiles() {
    var c = document.getElementById("c1");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
}
```

Comment: We can't find the issue in the code you provided. Can you provide more information?

Comment: well, what more information? I think I specified everything.

Comment: I don't see you calling the `tiles` function anywhere so I assume that is the problem but try using devtools (F12) and see if you get any errors.

Comment: First, determine if your file name is tiles.js, and secondly, you are not executing the tiles function.

Comment: I just modified this code https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_tut_text and they dont call the function either.

Comment: The difference is that they execute the code in global scope but you are creating a new function which you then must execute. Add `tiles();` on the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must call the function in js file

```
tiles();
```